# Show that $m^{*}(A \cup B) = m^{*}(B)$ if $m^{*}(A) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Where $m^{*}$ represents the outer measure set function.

If the sets were disjoint, the problem would be very simple, as I could just apply countable additivity:

$m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B) = 0 + m^*(B) = m^*(B)$

But I do not know that the sets are disjoint, therefore I can only say that the outer measure of the union is less than or equal to the outer measure of B, by countable subadditivity.

What am I missing?

I was also thinking about doing something along these lines:

$A \cup B = $ {remainder of A} + {elements of B  and elements that are in A and B} (which is the same things as B) and then applying the outer measure to this.  What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $B\subseteq A\cup B$ so $m^*(A\cup B)\ge m^*(B)$. Also sub-additivity gives

> $$m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(A) +m^*(B)=m^*(B)$$

which gives equality.

I'm not sure why you're extra worried about disjointness, it's still not a problem since monotonicity serves up the answer anyways:  let $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}$ cover $B$ and $\mathcal{V}=\{V_j\}$ cover $A$ so that $\mathcal{U}\cup\mathcal{V}$ covers $A\cup B$. Then as we can choose $V_j$ so that $\sum_j m^*(V_j)<\epsilon$ and $U_i$ so that $\sum_i m^*(U_i)\le m^*(B) + \epsilon$ we have that each $\epsilon>0$ allows

$$m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(B) + 2\epsilon$$

which gives equality.